# powershell start-process doesn't know about environment variable (PATH) changes

Tags: powershell, environment-variables

I use powershell to set a number of system environment variables, including the path. I then start some task with Start-Process. Unfortunately the new process has the same environment variables as those which powershell was started in. To reproduce the issue

1) Modify your path. I'm deleting `%JAVA_HOME%/bin`, open a command window and see that the `java` command does not work.

2) Start Powershell ISE

3) Add `%JAVA_HOME%/bin` to the system PATH. Open a new command window and see that the `java` command works.

4) In the previously opened Powershell window, submit the command `start cmd` to cause powershell to open a `cmd.exe` command window ("Command Prompt"). In the new command window verify that `java` does not work.

My expectation would be that a newly launched process would have its own fresh copy of the environment variables.

Can you tell me how to get powershell to launch a new task and have that task know the current environment?

I've tried

```
start cmd

Start-Process -FilePath "cmd"

Start-Process -FilePath "cmd" -UseNewEnvironment

& cmd
```

Thanks!

Comment: The `-UseNewEnvironment` switch for `Start-Process` is designed to do what you want, but it is (still) broken as of PowerShell Core 7.0.0-rc.2 - see [this GitHub issue](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/4671).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following command will start a process which is detached from the calling environment and have the new variable available for you to use.

`Invoke-CimMethod -ClassName Win32_Process -Name Create -Arguments @{CommandLine = "cmd.exe"}`